# If-And statement in JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to get this snippet of JSON:

```json
"industryCodes": [
      {
        "code": "1234567",
        "description": "industry description1",
        "typeDescription": "standard1",
        "typeCode": "765",
        "priority": 0
      },
      {
        "code": "Fail",
        "description": "industry description1",
        "typeDescription": "standard1",
        "typeCode": "765",
        "priority": 1
      },
      {
        "code": "Fail2",
        "description": "industry description2",
        "typeDescription": "standard2",
        "typeCode": "0001",
        "priority": 0
      }]
```

To Transform to this:

```json
"standard1" : [ {
      "value" : "1234567"
    } ]
```

Note: this is part of a larger transformation so the "[4]" in the next snippet is accurate.

This is my current code:

```json
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "industryCodes": {
      "*": {
        "typeCode": {
          "765": {
            "@(2,code)": "[4].attributes.standard1[0].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It outputs:

```json
"standard1" : [ {
      "value" : ["1234567","Fail"]
    } ]
```

The main issue is getting the second value of 'Fail' to not be included in the array. I need just the value that has a priority level of 0 and not all priority levels. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: yes, you can remove the "Fail" value from the "value" field in a "standard1" array. their are many ways to do it. 1. use the firstElement function. 2. "value":"@(1,value[0]) in modify-overwrite-beta".

Answer (score 0):

Then you just can pick the first index of the `industryCodes` array such as

```json
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "industryCodes": {
        "0": { // will return first component
          "typeCode": {
            "765": {
              "@(2,code)": "[4].attributes.standard1[0].value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What if there isn't a guarantee that it will be in the first component?

Comment: Welcome to SO @Kinetic . Well, indeed your  question is not clear enough to express exactly what component  you want to display. Can you edit the question to add related details please ?